# VSCode does not run the local python project

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code, conda

**In short:** I can't see the effect of my changes to a local repo when I run a test file that calls those changes.

---

There's a project that I've cloned locally and want to modify and test.

Here's the instruction in ReadMe.md

1. git clone https://xxx
2. conda create -n my_env python
3. activate my_env
4. python repo_root\xxx\setup.py

I opened the folder with a VSCode, created a new method "my_new_method", created a test.py that calls the method I made, but it doesn't recognize my method:

```
Exception has occurred: AttributeError
'Employee' object has no attribute 'my_new_method'
```

Here are what I have already done:

1. Made sure the file is saved
2. Located test.py in the same repo (I have tried all the combinations for locating the file)
3. Made sure that other methods work correctly
4. Tried both running and debugging

I'm using windows 10 and conda 4.4.10.

Comment: Post your code please.

Comment: there is nothing wrong with vscode show your `Employee` class

Comment: Thanks @Selcuk and Yugannhar Chaundhari for your comments. But the problem has nothing to do with the code and was resolved as Navid Vafaei explained

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short Version:**

Your VSCode should have the same python environment.

**Long Version:**

*Step 1:* Get the python path from your activated environment. [Here](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/integration/python-path/) is the documentation.

cheat-sheet: use  `Get-Command python` for PowerShell and `where python` for pretty much any other CLI.

*Step 2:* Make sure your VSCode has the same environment.

After opening the proper folder with VSCode, you will see its environment on the bottom left (sometimes slightly towards the middle as the branch name will go to the leftmost side):

[image]

After clicking on it, you will see the list of all environments:

[image]

Find the environment that you created (Please double check the path).

Comment: The main problem was that VSCode was not recognizing the changes in my local code. my_new_method was missing because it was getting it from another environment. When I set the correct environment, the problem was fixed.